# Different Magento stores for different country

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, stores

I want to create stores in Magento but I want those stores to be country specific. By **country specific store** means if the store is for France then its language will french and its product price will be completely different from the stores of other countries(stores). **Checkout method** of those stores may also differ according to the country.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same by creating multiple websites and you can able to set price of product website wise. But its quite difficult to use different checkout for all the websites. To do so you can create and different stores for each country.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this guide it should help you to setup websites and stores for htem: https://www.properhost.com/support/kb/30/How-To-Setup-Magento-With-Multiple-Stores-And-Domains

Comment: Thanks for the tip man. I'm trying the changes as per the link.